# Passing Variable Through Regex in Interation

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to pass a variable through a regex function and I am not getting the intended results

I tried the following code but it is not printing any regex results:

```
w = ["the small ball","the ball small","small the ball","small ball the","ball the small", "sball smalls the"]
y = ["the", "small", "ball"]
for j in y:
    for i in w:
        item = j
        print(item)
        try:
            m = re.search(r"%s\w+" %item, i)
            print(m.string)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

For each item in list y, I expected it to return all items from list w except for the last iteration as "ball" is not at the beginning of a word in the string.  However, I am not getting any results at all. Instead, with the exception handling removed, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Expected Results:

```
the
the small ball
the
the ball small
the
small the ball
the
small ball the
the
ball the small
the
sball smalls the

small
the small ball
small
the ball small
small
small the ball
small
small ball the
small
ball the small
small
sball smalls the

ball
the small ball
ball
the ball small
ball
small the ball
ball
small ball the
ball
ball the small
ball
```

It's supposed to search each instance of list y against all list w items.  If the word in list y is contained in the beginning of any word in a list w, then it returns the list w element.  Thus the last iteration of ball returns no value because it is not contained in the beginning of any word in "sball smalls the" while the others return a value since they produce a match.

Could you please advise how to tweak my code to get the expected results?

Comment: updated with expected results

Comment: do you meat to use `\s` or `\W` instead of `\w`? (`\w` is a shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` here)

Comment: I tried your suggestions but still getting the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First about the Exception: As the docs say:

> re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search

so if the expression you search for is not found you get `None` here instead of a Match object in `m`. In that case `m` has no attributes. Instead of

```
 print(m.string)
```

try

```
if m is not None:
    print m.string
else:
    print ""
```

Then the regular expression matches if your text is followed by any "word" characters. This is ok even when the match starts in the middle of a word.

If you want to check that the match starts with a word, you can use the "word boundary" special sequence '\b' at the beginning, i.e.:

```
   m = re.search(r"\b%s" %item, i)
```

Comment: This produces the same results as before.  Whether passing on the error, or handling the None values the way you suggested, it still doesn't help the regex function deliver the correct results

Comment: Ah, I skipped over what your regex is expected to do. Added this too?

Comment: It's supposed to search each instance of list y again all list w items.  If the word in list y is contained in the beginning of any word in a list w, then it returns the list w element.  Thus the last iteration of ball returns no value because it is not contained in the beginning of any word in "sball smalls the" while the others contain a value since they produce a match.

Comment: Updated the question with these details

Comment: Ok, I hope the regular expression added to my answer does the job. When I test with that expression I get search hits for all but the last string in `w`.